# a nicer way to create structs in a loop

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, loops, new-operator

I haven't coded in C++ in ages. And recently, I'm trying to work on something 
involving structs. Like this

```
typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;
```

Then in a loop, I'm trying to create new structs and put pointers to them them in a list.

```
Point* p;
int i, j;
while (condition){
    // compute values for i and j with some function...
    p = new Point;
    p* = {i, j}; //initialize my struct.
    list.append(p); //append this pointer to my list. 
}
```

Now, my question is it possible to simplify this? I mean, the pointer 
variable *p outside of the loop and calling p = new Point inside the loop. 
Isn't there a better/nicer syntax for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure:

```
Point * p  = new Point;
```

You should probably also give your Point class a constructor:

```
struct Point {      // note no need for typedef
    int x;
    int y;
    Point( int ax, int ay ) : x( ax ), y( ay ) {}
};
```

so that you can say:

```
Point * p  = new Point( i, j );
```

You may also want to make your list a list of Point values, rather than pointers, in which case you can avoid using dynamic allocation with new - always something to be avoided wherever possible in C++.

Comment: Oh! Thanks, Niel! So that will reserve the new p each time inside the loop? (sorry if it seems idiotic, I do mainly C all the time)

Comment: WAIT! I can add a method to a struct?! Wow! Thanks!

Comment: @sandra C is exactly the same in this regard. It's best to think of pa s being re-created each time through the loop. And structs and classes are basically the same thing in C++.

Comment: As Niel said, you can just do it like this:

while( condition )
{
    list.push_back( Point( i,j ) );
}

If you don't need pointers

Comment: @sandra Structs are essentially the same as classes - just with public access by default.  So yes, you can add constructors, methods, destructors etc. just like classes

Comment: Totally, I tried it and it worked like a charm! Thanks again guys (especially @Niel) :)

Answer (score 5):

The struct can have a constructor like:

```
struct Point{
    Point(int ax, int ay):x(ax), y(ay){}
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

and then the function can look like:

```
int i, j;
while (condition)
{
    list.append(new Point(i,j));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As structs are classes with public members by default, you could even create a constructor within the struct and initialize your point object within the loop like this:

```
Point* p = new Point(i,j);
```

Comment: Thanks @Simon, is the constructor in @Niel's solution required?

Comment: Yes of course. You have to explicitly declare the constructor, it won't be done automatically.

Comment: Thanks, Simon! In fact, that's what I've discovered by commenting out the constructor! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would venture a guess that it is extremely unlikely you really need to allocate something like a Point dynamically.

Most likely you want to add a constructor and store them by value:

```
list<Point> list;
list.append(Point(x, y));
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the Factory approach. Assuming that "Point" will be the base class of many objects, you can have a "Factory" that would return pointers.

Ex:

```
struct Point
{
        Point(int mx, int my):x(mx),y(my) {}
        int x;
        int y;
};

// Circle, Polygon, etc.

class Factory
{
public:
        static Point *getPoint(int mx, int my) { return new Point(mx, my); }
// Circle, Polygon, etc
};
```

Then in code someplace:

```
while(cond)
{
 list.append(Factory::getPoint(i, j));
}
```

Comment: Why would you assume that Point is a base class? If it were, it would be called Shape, wouldn't it?  This is ridiculously over-engineered.